# How to get rid of segmentation fault?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int getCharNum(int a) { return a / (8 * sizeof(char)); }
int getBitNum(int a) { return a % (8 * sizeof(char)); }
int fromCharNum(int a) { return a * 8 * sizeof(char); }
int get2DimI(int a) { return getCharNum(a) / 187500; }
int get2DimJ(int a) { return getCharNum(a) % 187500; }

void rle_compress(char *src, char *dst, int ls, int *ld) {
    uint8_t t[129];
    int i, j = 0, k = 0, keep;
    char out[187500];
    t[0] = src[j];
    while (j++ < ls) {
        t[1] = src[j];
        if (t[0] != t[1]) {
            i = 1;
            if (j < ls)
                do
                    t[++i] = src[++j];
                while (j < ls && i < 128 && t[i] != t[i - 1]);
            if ((keep = t[i] == t[i - 1]))
                --i;
            out[k++] = (char)i;
            t[0] = t[i];
            if (!keep)
                continue;
        }
        i = 2;
        do
            t[1] = src[++j];
        while (++i < 130 && t[0] == t[1]);
        out[k++] = i + 125;
        out[k++] = t[0];
        t[0] = t[1];
    }
    ld = &k;
    dst = out;
}

void rle_extract(char *src, char *dst, int ls) {
    int i, j, l = 0, k = 0, max;
    char out[187500];
    j = 0;
    while (k + 2 < ls) {
        i = src[k++];  //segfault
        j = src[k++];
        max = i + (i < 128 ? 1 : -126);
        while (max--)
            out[l++] = j;
    }
    dst = out;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int32_t n = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    int32_t a[n];
    int32_t b[] = { -1, -1, -1 };
    char **count;
    count = (char**)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char*));
    int count_l[] = { [999] = 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        count[i] = (char*)malloc(187500 * sizeof(char));
        char *temp = NULL;
        rle_compress(count[i], temp, 187500, &count_l[i]);
        free(count[i]);
        count[i] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char *src = count[get2DimI(a[i]) / 187500];
        char dst[187500];
        rle_extract(src, dst, count_l[i / 187500]);
        dst[get2DimJ(a[i])] ^= 1 << (getBitNum(a[i]));
        rle_compress(dst, count[get2DimI(a[i]) / 187500], 187500, &count_l[i]);
    }
    int32_t mv = 187500000 / (8 * sizeof(char));
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mv; i++) {
        char *src = count[i / 187500];
        char dst[187500];
        rle_extract(src, dst, count_l[i / 187500]);
        int32_t x = dst[i % 187500];
        if (x == 0)
            continue;
        for (int k = 0; k < 8 * sizeof(char); k++) {
            if ((x >> (k)) & 1) {
                b[j++] = fromCharNum(i) + k;
            }
        }
        //free(dst);
    }
    int m1 = min(b[0], min(b[1], b[2])),
        m3 = max(b[0], max(b[1], b[2])),
        m2 = b[0] + b[1] + b[2] - m1 - m3;
    printf("%d %d %d", m1, m2, m3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        free(count[i]);
    free(count);
    return 0;
}
```

How to fix this code?
I'm trying to compress byte array (which should compress greatly as `n` should be `<=1500000` and numbers are from `0` to `1.5*10^9`), but code gives me segfault on all testing inputs which I've tried. Without compress everything worked like a charm, but needed a lot of memory (and limits are 64MiB).

Comment: Use a debugger. It will tell you immediately and exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. That is the minimum info you should have already collected for yourself and for Stack Overlow. The debugger can also be used to step thru the code and examine it as it runs.

Comment: Also, suggest you apply good coding practice to make the code debuggable (for you and for others) - use comments, use meaningful variable names (not single letters), use `#define` values instead of magic numbers.

Comment: The issue that chrqlie mentioned re. `dst/out`. Either change the arg name from `dst` to `out` [and remove the local buffer] or do: `char *out = dst;` instead. It seems both compress and decompress functions have this issue. In `main`, you have `char dst[187500]` on the _stack_. In `main`, you could add `static` [or do `malloc` as you commented out]. This is just to eliminate the possibility that the segfault is caused by stack overflow. After the code is working you could revert this if you so choose.

Comment: @CraigEstey Shouldn't program use the same amount as before compress if edited like this https://ideone.com/lCFgw3? Also it's not the only problem as it still gives segfault, but according to gdb on another line.

Answer (score 0):

The code is obscure but there are some major problems:

- `void rle_extract(char *src, char *dst, int ls)` does not take the output buffer from its caller, nor does it return a pointer to it: `dst = out;` just updates the argument value, not the caller's variable passed as an argument. Furthermore `return 0;` from a `void` function is incorrect too.
- in any case, `rle_extract` should not return its local `out` buffer because it is only defined during the execution of the function and is discarded as soon as the function returns.

You should either pass the buffer as an argument or allocate it locally and return the pointer to the caller.

There might be other problems, there is no explanation for what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Code supposed to output unique values from input given that there are only 3 of them, all others present twice. Main idea: i-th bit represents i-th natural number (only numbers from 0 to 1.5*10^9 will present), corresponding bit is inverted each time number appears, so answer is all numbers of 1 bits. And because of limits for amount of numbers (less than 1500000) and limits for memory (64MiB) I have to compress byte array with run-length encoding. I tried commenting code https://ideone.com/lCFgw3 and fixing the stated problem, but there is still segfault (but in other place according to gdb).